# How to define xsd restrinction xs:enumeration to also accept empty element?

Tags: xsd

I have xsd schema that define `Gender` element that accepts only F or M value but I want it also to accept empty `<Gender/>` element. How to fix following schema?

```
...
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">        
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="M" />
            <xs:enumeration value="F" />
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
<xs:enumeration value="" />
```

?

However, this is bad practice. If you want to represent this information in the instance documents, you should *omit* the `<Gender>` element altogether, rather than providing an empty one.  Also, it's unclear what `<Gender/>` means - does this mean "no gender", or "unknown gender"?  If it's one of those possibilities, perhaps you should add those to the eneration:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">        
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="M" />
            <xs:enumeration value="F" />
            <xs:enumeration value="unknown" />
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I agree with your solution but I think it is perfectly valid. Empty string is a string value, it just happens to be empty.

I think it is very clear what `<Gender/>` means. It means no gender. Missing the gender element means that you are making no statement as to what the gender is (which could also mean unknown). This is very different to providing a value that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern instead:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">        
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(M|F)?"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: When you generate a java client, patterns are not generated as enums. So you have to know attribute value externally.